# Maximal normal series length for finite solvable groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Aluffi IV.3.2 goes as follows:

> Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group. Compute $\ell(G)$ in terms of $|G|$. Generalize to finite solvable groups.

Here $\ell(G)$ is the maximal length of a normal series in $G$.

First part looks straightforward: cyclic groups are abelian, so if $|G| = p_1^{k_1} \dots p_n^{k_n}$, then $\ell(G) = k_1 + \dots + k_n$.

But what about finite solvable groups? I don't think I see how to connect $\ell(G)$ with $|G|$ for them.

Comment: What do the composition factors of finite soluble groups look like? (Also, do you really mean a normal series, or a subnormal series? In other words, when you say a maximal normal series, do you mean a composition series?)

Comment: A maximal normal series is called a *chief series*. But I guess maximal subnormal series must be intended here, since otherwise the question does not have a unique answer.

Comment: If "composition series" is intended here, then the answer stays the same as in abelian case. That's because if $1=G_0\subseteq\cdots\subseteq G_n=G$ is a composition series (or any series of subgroups), then $|G|=|G_1/G_0|\cdots|G_n/G_{n−1}|$. And if $G$ is solvable then $G_m/G_{m-1}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_p$.